# Remove link from title of custom content type in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I have created a custom content type that includes a title, body and an image. I am displaying this content type in a views slideshow which is working fine.

The problem is that the 'Title' on each slide is linked to a stand-alone page for that individual node. This is undesirable. Is it possible to remove this link, or at least change where it goes?

When viewing the content type, there is no 'edit' (or delete) link for the Title field on the 'manage fields' tab, and on the 'manage displays' tab, the title field does not appear at all, though it claims no fields are hidden. Why are we prevented from controlling the behavior of this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view configuration, click "Field: Title" and un-check "Link this field to the original piece of content".

If you can't find it, you can also add some css to that title. For example:

```
.view-id-case_studies h1 a{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: I had format set to show 'content' instead of fields, preventing me from accessing the field level editing in the view. Once I changed the format to show fields instead this solution worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can target a field defined in the Display Manager by creating a custom "tpl.php" file in the default theme template folder called "field--field-name.tpl.php"